# using jquery to do an overlay with iframe. Won't retain css after first link

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jwplayer

so I got jwplayer working with iframe. I also have multiple links on the same page to open different videos via iframe. When I choose the first video at the top of the page, it works really well, when I choose any other video it won't maintain any of the css. I'm using prettyphoto for the overlay, however, I did try other versions and had the same issue.

Thanks!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT='7800; URL=index.php'> 
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="0" />


<!-- include the JQuery Tools -->
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://singingfromthecenter.com/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://singingfromthecenter.com/js/jquery/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- / END -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://singingfromthecenter.com/css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="prettyPhoto main stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://singingfromthecenter.com/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>


</head>

<body>

        <ul class="gallery clearfix">
                <li><a href="vids/sc1.html?iframe=true&width=640&height=500"  rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" title="more about sftc">link 1</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
<br /><br /><br />

    <ul class="gallery clearfix">
                <li><a href="vids/sc1.html?iframe=true&width=640&height=500"  rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" title="more about sftc">link 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
<br /><br /><br />

    <ul class="gallery clearfix">
                <li><a href="vids/sc1.html?iframe=true&width=640&height=500"  rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" title="more about sftc">link 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
<br /><br /><br />


    </div>

</div>


<div id="close">

</div>


</div>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){




            $("area[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();

            $(".gallery:first a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animation_speed:'normal',theme:'light_square',slideshow:3000, autoplay_slideshow: false});
            $(".gallery:gt(0) a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animation_speed:'fast',slideshow:10000, hideflash: true});

            $("#custom_content a[rel^='prettyPhoto']:first").prettyPhoto({
                custom_markup: '<div id="map_canvas" style="width:260px; height:265px"></div>',
                changepicturecallback: function(){ initialize(); }
            });

            $("#custom_content a[rel^='prettyPhoto']:last").prettyPhoto({
                custom_markup: '<div id="bsap_1259344" class="bsarocks bsap_d49a0984d0f377271ccbf01a33f2b6d6"></div><div id="bsap_1237859" class="bsarocks                    bsap_d49a0984d0f377271ccbf01a33f2b6d6" style="height:260px"></div><div id="bsap_1251710" class="bsarocks bsap_d49a0984d0f377271ccbf01a33f2b6d6"></div>',
                changepicturecallback: function(){ _bsap.exec(); }
            });
        });


</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are running this?

Comment: Sure do, http://singingfromthecenter.com/test2.html

Comment: It might have to do with how the html5 player renders on the page. Can you try to set the primary variable to flash to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: I changed it, same issue: 

<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('playerXa7yK1bZ').setup({
        playlist: 'https://jwpsrv.com/feed/Xa7yK1bZ.rss',
        width: '100%',
        aspectratio: '4:3',
        autostart: 'true',
        primary: 'flash'
    });
</script>

Comment: Ethan, on a different note, I sent you a message through JWplayer asking about JWplayer and popups. It was regarding this link.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/36326/jwplayer-popup-in-the-browser/

Reason I bring this up, is there a better way to work jwplayer and overlays?

Comment: I wrote a lightbox using JS that you might be interested in, I will send you a sample of it :)

Comment: oooh yes please :-). Thanks!

Also, I discovered the issue with pretty photo. It seems it's with the  <ul class="gallery clearfix"> Once I add a second ul it only works for the first one in the page.

Comment: Glad you got it. Please email me at ethan [at] jwplayer [dot] com for the demo.

Comment: thanks Ethan! will do